# Yii log skip 404 errors

Tags: php, yii, http-status-code-404

Maybe exist solution to skip 404 exceptions ? I'mean not store this messages in log file ?

```
2015/04/09 12:28:52 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'Невозможно обработать запрос "offer/downloadOffer".' in /var/www/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php:286
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('offer/downloadO...')
#1 /var/www/yii/framework/base/CApplication.php(184): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#2 /var/www/LAP/www/index.php(16): CApplication->run()
#3 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/offer/downloadOffer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is exclude categories.

```
array(
'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
'categories' => '!exception.CHttpException.404'
),
array(
'class' => 'CEmailLogRoute',
'categories' => '!exception.CHttpException.*'
),
```

Comment: Are you certain this is the correct solution to this problem? See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47287472/667544). I think you'll find this will exclude **all** categories as none will match!

Comment: This answer is incorrect, it will suppress EVERY category.  See the comment above, and use another solution.

Answer (score 8):

For Yii 2.0, you can make your config/main.php like this:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                    'except' => ['yii\web\HttpException:404'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 7):

For Yii 1.1, the correct way to exclude a category is to use the `except` key. Prepending a `!` in the `categories` key as per the accepted answer will actually result in only matching categories that start with a `!`. So whilst it might appear to work, you're actually going to be suppressing all categories. See the `filterAllCategories()` function of the source code - there's no processing of the `!` character, only for the `*` wildcard: [GitHub Source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/04f97932ddfbf9c5bdaae0a6a41b851544704a27/framework/logging/CLogger.php).

I tried the `!exception.CHttpException.404` approach in the accepted answer and thought I'd solved the issue of hiding the 404 errors, but then I realised after much hair pulling that this was resulted in **no logs** being logged!

The correct syntax to ignore a category is:

```
array(
   'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
   'except' => 'exception.CHttpException.404'
)
```

Comment: This solution worked well, suppressed what I needed, and not everything. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I think we should use an array
   'except' =>[ 'exception.CHttpException.404']